# Animate frame changes from viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to move my buttons and labels to specific locations when the view loads. At first everything is in the center and when it loads everything is supposed to expand to designated locations. I have this but the icons and labels don't move. It works if I make a button in the same view and put the code in it though.

```
     #import "DashViewController.h"

@interface DashViewController ()

@end

@implementation DashViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)backb:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)loadanim:(id)sender{
    [self moveIcons];
}


-(void)moveIcons{

    CGRect framehi = homeIcon.frame;
    framehi.origin.x = 15;
    framehi.origin.y = 70;
    CGRect framehl = homeLabel.frame;
    framehl.origin.x = -8;
    framehl.origin.y = 136;

    CGRect framesmi = smediaIcon.frame;
    framesmi.origin.x = 131;
    framesmi.origin.y = 70;
    CGRect framesml = smediaLabel.frame;
    framesml.origin.x = 108;
    framesml.origin.y = 136;

    CGRect framemi = mediaIcon.frame;
    framemi.origin.x = 249;
    framemi.origin.y = 70;
    CGRect frameml = mediaLabel.frame;
    frameml.origin.x = 225;
    frameml.origin.y = 136;

    CGRect frameni = newsIcon.frame;
    frameni.origin.x = 15;
    frameni.origin.y = 211;
    CGRect framenl = newsLabel.frame;
    framenl.origin.x = -8;
    framenl.origin.y = 277;

    CGRect framebi = bullyIcon.frame;
    framebi.origin.x = 131;
    framebi.origin.y = 211;
    CGRect framebl = bullyLabel.frame;
    framebl.origin.x = 108;
    framebl.origin.y = 277;

    CGRect framespi = sportsIcon.frame;
    framespi.origin.x = 249;
    framespi.origin.y = 211;
    CGRect framespl = sportsLabel.frame;
    framespl.origin.x = 225;
    framespl.origin.y = 277;

    CGRect framesti = staffIcon.frame;
    framesti.origin.x = 15;
    framesti.origin.y = 355;
    CGRect framestl = staffLabel.frame;
    framestl.origin.x = -8;
    framestl.origin.y = 421;

    CGRect framehbi = handbookIcon.frame;
    framehbi.origin.x = 131;
    framehbi.origin.y = 355;
    CGRect framehbl = handbookLabel.frame;
    framehbl.origin.x = 108;
    framehbl.origin.y = 421;

    CGRect frameai = aboutIcon.frame;
    frameai.origin.x = 249;
    frameai.origin.y = 355;
    CGRect frameal = aboutLabel.frame;
    frameal.origin.x = 225;
    frameal.origin.y = 421;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        homeIcon.frame = framehi;
        homeLabel.frame = framehl;
        smediaIcon.frame = framesmi;
        smediaLabel.frame = framesml;
        mediaIcon.frame = framemi;
        mediaLabel.frame = frameml;
        newsIcon.frame = frameni;
        newsLabel.frame = framenl;
        bullyIcon.frame = framebi;
        bullyLabel.frame = framebl;
        sportsIcon.frame = framespi;
        sportsLabel.frame = framespl;
        staffIcon.frame = framesti;
        staffLabel.frame = framestl;
        handbookIcon.frame = framehbi;
        handbookLabel.frame = framehbl;
        aboutIcon.frame = frameai;
        aboutLabel.frame = frameal;
    }];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self moveIcons];
   }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: see my updated answer. just some debugging suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put geometry-related code in `viewDIdLoad` as view frames are not yet set at that point. Also animation code makes no sense before the view is onscreen - try moving it to `viewDidAppear`.

*update*

Judging by your efforts and comments, your issue is as much 'how to debug' as it is 'what's wrong with my code' (other than where you call it, i can't see any problem with your code!).

IN summary
- you have moved the code to a separate method (in fact you mention a "custom void statement " - I am not sure what you mean by that, use a method as per my code below...)
- you call the same method from `viewDiDAppear` and from a button action with `[self animate];` 
- called from `viewDidAppear`, it doesn't run. Called from a button action, it does.

So you need to find out *exactly* where the code is failing.

First I suggest reducing your code to a minimum for testing. Animate just one object:

```
- (void) animate {
      CGRect framehi = homeIcon.frame;
      framehi.origin.x = 15;
      framehi.origin.y = 70;

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.25];

     homeIcon.frame = framehi;

     [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Do a bit of logging before and after you call the method:

```
   NSLog(@"pre-animated frame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(homeIcon.frame);
   [self animate];
   NSLog(@"post-animated frame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(homeIcon.frame);
```

From which you can tell whether the frame is getting set in the animaton method. You don't make it clear in your comments - with a failed animation is the frame also failing to get set? If it is just the animation that is failing do you have any other animation code running that may be interfering with it? Are you transitioning to this view in an unusual way?

Try calling the animation method from other methods, for example `viewWillAppear:animated` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. Are you *certain* that your `viewDidAppear` method is definitely getting called?

Put this log statement at the start of all of your relevant methods:
      `NSLog(@"%s",__func__);`
It will show you exactly which methods are called, when.

Try putting a breakpoint at the start of `viewWillAppear` and step through, watching the variables to see what is getting set where. Is it *just* the animation that is failing?

If so try using an animation block to trigger the animations:

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
          homeIcon.frame = framehi;
   }];
```

(that shouldn't make the difference but its the more modern way)

You need to come up with some better clues as to the error because it is not in the code you have posted.  As I said, I have tested your exact code in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDiDAppear` and it works fine. Perhaps your method signatures are not correct and they are not getting called?

When you get a better idea, if you still can't solve it, then either edit your question or start a new one. If you edit your question, add the exact test code you are using including method calls/signatures, log results.

But don't add results as comments, it's harder for other people to help out.

Good luck

Comment: Where is the viewDidAppear? Do I just create it?

Comment: @SiDiX It is the method you should override instead of `viwDidLoad` (It is called later in the view loading process)

Comment: - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated ?

Comment: @SiDiX yes. don't forget to call `[super viewDidAppear:animated]` inside your method.

Comment: if you look at the edit, I put the viewDidAppear and it's still not working.

Comment: why don't you just put everything in UIView animation block..

Put this in viewDidAppear.

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay: 0 options: 0 animations:
 ^(void) {
    
//Your code

 }
completion: nil];

It might help you.

Comment: @SiDiX - I assume u deleted the `viewDidLoad` code? Also I have not checked your animation code, are you sure it works if run from a button? If so it should also work in `viewDidAppear`. You could put a log statement or a breakpoint in to be sure the code is being called.

Comment: Yes, it completely works with a button, but for some reason it's not working, and I did delete the viewDidLoad.

Comment: @SIDIX, something else is wrong with your code, as I have tested it in `viewDidAppear` and it works. As I already suggested - put a breakpoint or a log statement eg `NSLog(@"viewDidAppear fired");` into `viewDidAppear` to check your code is getting called.

Comment: @HeWas, I put the NSLog into the ViewDidAppear and it did Log, I really don't know what's wrong. At the start all the icons and labels are overlapped in the center. Could that be the problem? I don't know it's working if it's within an IBAction.

Comment: @HeWas, I just tested putting the NSLog before the actual animation code and it logged however, when I put it after the animation code it did not log. (Animation works fine in an IBAction)

Comment: @SiDiX - after the code is run are the objects still in their original location (overlapped in the center), or in their intended final location? Try moving  the framesetting/animation code into a separate method that you can call EITHER from viewDidAppear OR from you test button... so that _exactly the same code_ is called from both places. Then report what happens (i) after the view has appeared and then (ii) after you trigger the button action. Update your question with some results. Another suggestion: simplify your test code to only 1 label and 1 icon see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @HeWas, Ok, so I made a custom void statement where I put the code, I call it from the viewDidAppear by saying [self VoidStatement]; and I put it in an IBAction. Nothing gets logged but when I click on the button it works. However, it doesn't work on the viewDidAppear.

Comment: @HeWas, So I did what you suggested with the NSLOGS and it is logging a new location, however, the icon did not move to that location.

Comment: @HeWas, the code has been updated. Also the animation doesn't work and the object does not move to the desired location.

Comment: @SiDiX Where do you initialize all these views (homeIcon, homeLabel, etc.) ? There's a chance they're `nil` when `moveIcons` is called from `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything from viewDidLoad as for now and then change your code in viewDidAppear to the following:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGRect framehi = homeIcon.frame;
    framehi.origin.x = 15;
    framehi.origin.y = 70;
    CGRect framehl = homeLabel.frame;
    framehl.origin.x = -8;
    framehl.origin.y = 136;

    CGRect framesmi = smediaIcon.frame;
    framesmi.origin.x = 131;
    framesmi.origin.y = 70;
    CGRect framesml = smediaLabel.frame;
    framesml.origin.x = 108;
    framesml.origin.y = 136;

    CGRect framemi = mediaIcon.frame;
    framemi.origin.x = 249;
    framemi.origin.y = 70;
    CGRect frameml = mediaLabel.frame;
    frameml.origin.x = 225;
    frameml.origin.y = 136;

    CGRect frameni = newsIcon.frame;
    frameni.origin.x = 15;
    frameni.origin.y = 211;
    CGRect framenl = newsLabel.frame;
    framenl.origin.x = -8;
    framenl.origin.y = 277;

    CGRect framebi = bullyIcon.frame;
    framebi.origin.x = 131;
    framebi.origin.y = 211;
    CGRect framebl = bullyLabel.frame;
    framebl.origin.x = 108;
    framebl.origin.y = 277;

    CGRect framespi = sportsIcon.frame;
    framespi.origin.x = 249;
    framespi.origin.y = 211;
    CGRect framespl = sportsLabel.frame;
    framespl.origin.x = 225;
    framespl.origin.y = 277;

    CGRect framesti = staffIcon.frame;
    framesti.origin.x = 15;
    framesti.origin.y = 355;
    CGRect framestl = staffLabel.frame;
    framestl.origin.x = -8;
    framestl.origin.y = 421;

    CGRect framehbi = handbookIcon.frame;
    framehbi.origin.x = 131;
    framehbi.origin.y = 355;
    CGRect framehbl = handbookLabel.frame;
    framehbl.origin.x = 108;
    framehbl.origin.y = 421;

    CGRect frameai = aboutIcon.frame;
    frameai.origin.x = 249;
    frameai.origin.y = 355;
    CGRect frameal = aboutLabel.frame;
    frameal.origin.x = 225;
    frameal.origin.y = 421;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        homeIcon.frame = framehi;
        homeLabel.frame = framehl;
        smediaIcon.frame = framesmi;
        smediaLabel.frame = framesml;
        mediaIcon.frame = framemi;
        mediaLabel.frame = frameml;
        newsIcon.frame = frameni;
        newsLabel.frame = framenl;
        bullyIcon.frame = framebi;
        bullyLabel.frame = framebl;
        sportsIcon.frame = framespi;
        sportsLabel.frame = framespl;
        staffIcon.frame = framesti;
        staffLabel.frame = framestl;
        handbookIcon.frame = framehbi;
        handbookLabel.frame = framehbl;
        aboutIcon.frame = frameai;
        aboutLabel.frame = frameal;
    }];
}
```

Comment: I deleted the viewDidLoad and replaced my viewDidAppear with this, but my icons aren't moving to the appropriate locations.

Comment: if they are getting animated (aka moving) then the code that i mentioned is working properly. If they are not moving at appropriate locations then, it is to do with the CGRect calculations. You'll have to tweak the values of your rects.

Comment: What do now have in viewDidLoad: and viewDidAppear:?